# How to have base-4.8.1.0 on ghc-7.10.1?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, haskell-platform

Just installed ghc-7.10.1, followed by cabal-1.22.6 on Debian 7.8 (*from sources*). I'm following *minimal* installation of Haskell from http://www.extellisys.com/articles/haskell-on-debian-wheezy (I replaced 7.8.4 by 7.10.1, and downloaded latest `haskell-platform-master` from [github](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform))

But, whenever I try to install Haskell Platform, installation breaks minutes later at this point:

```
Building hptool-0.1...
Preprocessing executable 'hptool' for hptool-0.1...
***
*** Running hptool
***
# cabal (for build/package/hscolour-1.23/deps)
Error when running Shake build system:
* build-all
* build-source
* build/product/haskell-platform-7.10.2.tar.gz
* build/lists/build.packages
* build/package/hscolour-1.23/deps
Error computing dependencies of hscolour-1.23:
Resolving dependencies...

cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: hscolour-1.23 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of hscolour-1.23)
rejecting: base-4.8.0.0/installed-1b6..., 4.8.0.0, 4.7.0.2, 4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0,
4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0,
4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0, 4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0, 3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global
constraint requires ==4.8.1.0)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

How to solve that? 
How to have base 4.8.1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching in the `haskell-platform` repository for mentions of `base` constraints, I found in hptool/src/Releases2015.hs [a `hp_7_10_2` value of type `Release` which seems to specify the 4.8.1.0 constraint](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/blob/a2fe07c0665b1fa471e97b373fda5979990dee22/hptool/src/Releases2015.hs#L111), as well as an analogous `hp2015_2_0_0` with a 4.8.0.0 constraint. That `hp_7_10_2` value is used to specify the release to install in [src/Main.hs](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/blob/a2fe07c0665b1fa471e97b373fda5979990dee22/hptool/src/Main.hs#L85), so I guess if you change that line to use `hp2015_2_0_0` you will get dependencies that can be satisfied. The alternative would be installing GHC 7.10.2 (which includes `base` 4.8.1.0), which is still unreleased (however, there is a [release candidate](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.ghc.devel/9024), and the official release should happen soon).

Comment: Changing `hp_7_10_2` to `hp2015_2_0_0` in `src/Main.hs` did it! +1 for that.